# Question about finding cube root by hand

Tags: arithmetic

To find the square root of $125$ by hand:

$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
 & 1,25.00 & 11.1  \\
 &1  &   \\
\hline
21  & \space \space \space \space 25 & \\
&\space \space \space \space21 & \\
\hline  
221& \space \space \space \space \space \space 4.00& \\
&\space \space \space \space \space \space221&
\end{array}
$$

Thus the answer is $11.1$ and however many decimals one would desire. If you look at the method to calculate the square root, it quickly becomes obvious it is utilizing $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2 = a^2+b(2a+b)$. The first digit of the solution is $1$, which is $a$, then this value is doubled and a $b$ is estimated, and finally multiplied by $b$ in the answer, or in other words $b(2a+b)$.

The cube root is something similar. Finding the cube root of $1278$ by hand:

$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
 & 1,278 & 1  \\
 &1  &   \\
\hline
300\times1^2=300  & \space \space \space \space 278 & \\
30\times1\times b=?&\space \space \space \space & \\
b^2=?& & \\
\hline  
\end{array}
$$

At this juncture obviously $300$ exceeds the partial dividend $278$, so the answer gets a $0$ and I bring down a new set of three digits, $000$:

$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
 & 1,278.000 & 10.8  \\
 &1  &   \\
\hline
300\times10^2=30000  & \space \space \space \space 278.000 & \\
30\times10\times 8=2400&\space \space \space \space 259.712& \\
8^2=64& & \\
\hline  
& \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  18288& \\
\end{array}
$$

Thus the answer is $10.8$ and however many decimals one would desire. The cube root method utilizes $(10a+b)^3=1000a^3+300a^2b+30ab^2+b^3=1000a^3+b(300a^2+30ab+b^2)$. What I don't understand is why $10a$? Because intuitively I would think it should be $(a+b)^3$.

Comment: because the floor of the cubic root of 1278 is a 2 digit number which can be shown  as $(ab)=10a +b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  If you have a two digit number represented by $10a+b$, $b$ represents the units.  What does $a$ represent?

> (In general, a number can be represented by $10^a x_1 + 10^{a-1} x_2 + 10^{a-2} x_3 \dots 10^{a-(n-1)} x_{n-1} + 10^{(a-n)} x_n$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots x_{n-1}, x_n$ are the digits of that number.)

Comment: But why is it $(a+b)^2$ in the square root case?

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson: It isn't. It's $(10a+b)^2$. The fact that the left-hand component is $20a+b$ is concealed by the fact that you simply concatenate the two numbers. That is, you write $2a$ first, and then when you concatenate the digit $b$ at the end, you implicitly multiply the $2a$ by $10$.